# Error 1219. Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user

Tags: windows-xp, net-use

I am trying to map network drive, but get error 1219 on Windows XP:

```
net use z: \\serverA\tests password /user:serverA\alex
```

I have tried

```
net use * /del /yes
```

But it has no effect, and the

```
net use
```

shows empty list.

\\serverA\tests is a valid path, as I can open it in Explorer.

What can be done?

**EDIT:** After reboot it works. But any ideas are still very welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will usually be caused by a handle left open.  Download [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) to find it, and try to close the program that has it open (don't close the handle itself).  If it turns out to be `explorer.exe`, it's probably a buggy preview handler/shell extension.

If you can't find the handle, you can always try using the IP address of ServerA to create a new connection with different credentials, e.g.

```
net use z: \\10.1.2.3\tests password /user:serverA\alex
```

---

Yes, sorry - use *Find Handle or DLL* with \\ServerA to find the program.

Comment: With 'Find > Find Handle Or Dll...' I can find processes using the shared folder. Thought I can't reproduce the issue again, this is a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: Solved for me too but search for ServerA not \\ServerA

Comment: Just wanted to say, use the "Find > Find Handle Or DLL" as @alex2k8 pointed out.  I couldn't find squat with all the info Process Explorer presented, but using the find tool, I was able to quickly search for the server I was attempting to connect to "ServerA" EX, and found the process easily, and mapping worked.  Hours pulling my hair out (couldn't restart) and this post saved me, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

To open it in Explorer it has to be able to logon using your credentials (or the ones you provide when it eventually asks you for credentials).

After that you have a connection and would have to disconnect before you could remap the share with different credentials.  (see "Disconnect network share")

You could map it persistently - that way it would always use the credentials you provide.